# ASP.NET Core 3.1 ignoring System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyName when returning response body

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1, system.text.json

I recently changed my ASP.NET Core application to target 3.1 from 2.2.  I also changed from using Newtonsoft for JSON serialization to System.Text.Json.  In the process I have changed a number of response class properties to use JsonPropertyNameAttribute (from the Newtonsoft JsonPropertyAttribute).

However, I have now noticed the application is ignoring the JsonPropertyNameAttribute and serializing the property name to camel case instead.

For example:

```cs
[JsonPropertyName("handsets")]
public IEnumerable<GetHandsetResponse> AllHandsets { get; set; }
```

The response object field is being output as `allHandsets` in the response and not `handsets` as specified by the JsonPropertyName.

I'm guessing I'm missing something in the Startup.cs of the application to tell it to use System.Text.Json however I have no idea what.  What might I be missing?

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the behavior you are seeing. Can you please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that I can run locally to see the error? What does your `GetHandsetResponse` model look like? I created a webapi using `dotnet new webapi` and I see `handsets` in the response JSON.

Comment: Unfortunately due to the project and the size of it that is not going to be possible.  However, `GetHandsetResponse` itself is not the problem rather the name given via the JsonPropertyName (its doing the same thing for all response objects properties).  Are you aware of any switch that is required in Startup.cs to tell the application to use System.Text.Json rather than Newtonsoft's notation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that deep down in the common code called from Startup.cs - ConfigureServices() of the application there is a call to `.AddNewtonsoftJson()` (on the returned IMvcBuilder type).  Removing that method call appears to properly revert the application back to using the System.Text.Json serializer.